# Is it possible to change the scrolling in the site to scroll one question each scroll step?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, question-lists, scrolling

Is there a technology that the site might implement such that when scrolling down with the mouse scroll button one bar of question will be scrolled (and not a question and a half as it is now)?

That would give the interface a better and cleaner feel.

Comment: I've no scroll wheel, but: are you sure it's not a number of pixels right now (and hence very machine-dependent)? Like: what if you first zoom out using Ctrl/Command Minus, or zoom in using Ctrl/Command Plus?

Comment: @Arjan It probably is, but there might be a Javascript event when the user scrolls that they could try to mess with; I'm just speculating though

Comment: There's some CSS2 [page-break-before](http://w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp) and the like, but I doubt that affects the scroll wheel. (It would surely mess with printing, but it could be excluded from the [`@media print`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp) CSS then.)